# Rich Snippets for Wordpress

Tags: google

[Rich Snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) look like a good tool for the webmaster's toolbox.

Do you know of any way of integrating Rich Snippets into Wordpress?

Comment: Try a schema plugin for WordPress, like [Slim SEO Schema](https://wpslimseo.com/slim-seo-schema/).

Comment: @AnhTran, Slim SEO Schema wouldn't replace Rank Math SEO's schema solution, would it?

Comment: it wouldn't. It will add its own schemas that you build to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, the Rich Snippets tool is purely for *testing* what the formatting/markup of your content is already. It does nothing on its own.

Most of the markup that the tool is looking for is usually baked into a theme. WordPress helps this along a little bit by incorporating parts of the hAtom format into the `body_class()`, `post_class()`, and [possibly] `comment_class()` functions. If you browse through the code of Twenty Twelve, you'll see that it implements more hAtom formatting with classes like `entry-title` and `entry-content`.

There may be plugins that augment those `*_class()` and other functions or add information to the head, but a lot of making a site "rich" is up to the theme. Plugins can mostly only control their markup (which is why the GD Star Rating plugin can make the data it stores rich but won't help you with anything else). Yoast's [WordPress SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) also can help with getting Google+ author info and opengraph data onto your site.

I often use the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin to add more granular data to my WordPress sites. This lets me markup the specific pieces of data in theme files. (I wrote [a blog post](http://mrwweb.com/schemas-microformats-machine-readable-websites/) about marking up a People directory that the Rich Snippet tool can interpret. I've also done a business directory in a very similar way.) For the ACF fields, I like to use the vocabularies and markup specified by [Schema.org](http://schema.org), which is created by a consortium including Google.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you're looking for & how customized output. However, here are some plugins to get started. Hope this helps

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/ (This one is more widely used. Good for review-type site/blog)

Or, more can be found here
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/rich-snippets

Update back with the ones you find useful for others to know as well.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure while implementing any markup, you need to be very selective while choosing and incorporating any plugin for Rich snippet. You won't get any benefit if it will not be implemented properly.

You can use Google's structured data markup testing tool at - https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
once you implement any markup.